# What is the scaling factor of the grease pencil brush radius when using thickness as World space?

Tags: grease-pencil, brushes

The brush radius of the grease pencil is exposed in "pixels" in the UI and in the API.

```
size
    Radius of the brush in pixels
    Type: int in [1, 5000], default 35
```

In the Grease pencil object properties > Strokes, the stroke thickness can be configured to be either in Screen space or in World space. World space is the default.

There is also the stroke line_width, also in "pixels".

```
line_width
    Thickness of stroke (in pixels)
    Type: int in [1, 1000], default 0
```

Question: When thickness is using World space, how is the stroke width computed and how can we set it to a specific amount of World units? (either in the UI on in Python)

edit: after some more testing lining up brush strokes on the grid the scaling seems to be around 1000 px ~= 0.57 world units.
While for the stroke `line_width` property the value seems to be in thousandths of world units (1000 = 1 WU) as the diameter of the stroke, and modulated by the point `pressure` in 0..1.